# Wordpress: How to make page contents dynamic

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sorry if the question seems basic. I'm currently studying wordpress and i am making my own theme. What i would like to know is how to make the content of my page dynamic. Say, the homepage has an image slider on top and a brief description below. Right now it is hard coded. How can i dynamically add image to my slider from the dashboard? And update the description below? I've read about custom fields and this tutorial http://www.janes.co.za/dynamic-wordpress-slideshow-without-plugin/

And now I'm more confused. How would i be able to make multiple contents in my pages dynamic?

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to make custom post, and use its thumbnail's photos as your carousel photos. Title for whatever you want, content can be your description below image or whatever your design is.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. The description is separate from the carousel. They are not related. the description contains a short paragraph and a link to about page. So, I need to update multiple contents is one page. i hope i explained well. :)

Answer (score 0):

A way to make areas dynamic is to use the plugin, [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). Read its documentation. It allows content to changed from the dashboard in pages (yes pages not posts as posts are already dynamic).